# Tradingview timeframe period conditions

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Newbe with Pine Script, I would like to code something like this:

```
if (timeframe.perdiod == "D") // daily
plot(.......)

if(timeframe.period == "m5") // 5min
plot(........)
```

Comment: that is doable, what type of plot you use though will determine how you write it. You can plot labels, boxes and lines within an if statement, but you can't use plot or plotshape....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IF**

Some Pine Script™ built-in functions cannot be called from within the local blocks of conditional structures. They are: [plot()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Conditional_structures.html#introduction)
Use a *ternary* in the plot series
Something like this:

```
myLine = math.avg(ta.highest(9),ta.lowest(9))
isdaily = timeframe.period == "D"
plot(isdaily ? myLine : na)

is5min = timeframe.period == "5"
plot(is5min ? myLine : na)
```

Comment: Thanks @Gu5tavo71 but how do you add this variable in plot() function:

`myLine = math.avg(ta.highest(9),ta.lowest(9))`

Comment: I just modified my previous answer